Re-paint of controls fails when Edit control throws Tooltip Warning in MFC Dialog
I was designing a MFC dialog using CXTPDialog CXTP Derived controls. I have used the CSliderCtrl and CXTPEdit.
I have set some defined ranges for each of the parameters for the edit control. Whenever the value is exceeded and a tooltip indicating the warning pops up, the controls associated with it (and also adjacent controls) have painting issues like below.
The slider control UI seems broken, which is adjacent to the CEdit control. (The gray part showing up)

Multiple controls facing paint Issues (The gray part showing up)

The dialog that includes these controls is loaded into the parent dialog using Dialog.Create() and moves into its current position. This is the whole view of the dialog with the control

The OninitColor of the Dialog is defined as below. SetupDialog is the Dialog having controls.
HBRUSH SetupDialog::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor)
{

    HBRUSH hBrush = nullptr;

    if (nCtlColor == CTLCOLOR_DLG)
    {
        hBrush = m_BrushWhite; // Use the white brush for the dialog background
    }
    else if (nCtlColor == CTLCOLOR_EDIT || nCtlColor == CTLCOLOR_LISTBOX)
    {
        hBrush = m_BrushEdit;
    }
    else
    {
        pDC->SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);
        pDC->SetTextColor(ThemeDefines()->clrDarkTextColor);

        hBrush = m_BrushWhite;
    }

    return hBrush == nullptr ? CXTPDialog::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor) : hBrush;
}

DDX part for the seed edit box and slider:
void SetupDialog::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
CXTPDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_DR_SEED_COUNT_EDIT, m_editUMAPSeed);
DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_DR_SEED_SLIDER, m_sliderUMAPSeed);
DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_DR_SEED_COUNT_EDIT, m_nUMAPSeed);
DDV_MinMaxInt(pDX, m_nUMAPSeed, MIN_SEED, MAX_SEED);
}

I can see this might have something to do with the focus issue, but I am unable to pinpoint how to fix these.
Do I need to override ondraw() or other functions as well?
I have tried to look up online regarding the specifics of this issue, but nothing turned out good.
